# How to edit a string type column of a python dataframe according to rule?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a university work, we have some geographic coordinates of world locations in a pandas dataframe:

```
      df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['Paris', 'New York', 'Rio', 'Airport GRU', 'ORLY'],
               'GEO': ['POINT (2.31647 48.85)',
                       'POINT (-73.993457389558 40.731499671618)',
                       'POINT (-43.2 -22.9)',
                       'POINT (-46.47313507388693 -23.429382262746415)',
                       'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY']})

      print(df)

        NAME                      GEO
       Paris                   POINT (2.31647 48.85)
       New York                POINT (-73.993457389558 40.731499671618)
        Rio                    POINT (-43.2 -22.9)
      Airport GRU              POINT (-46.47313507388693 -23.429382262746415)
        ORLY                   GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
```

I would like to edit the 'GEO' column. Initially, I would like to disregard the word 'POINT', then I would like to put it in (Latitude, Longitude) format, as the column is in POINT (Longitude Latitude) format (and it's also being a comma).

To solve this, I created two separate columns to store the LAT and LONG (this part is working):

```
       df2 = df.join(df['GEO'].str.extract(r'(?P<LONG>-?\d+\.\d+) (?P<LAT>-?\d+\.\d+)').astype(float))

      print(df2)

         NAME            GEO                                          LONG      LAT
        Paris       POINT (2.31647 48.85)                           2.316470   48.85000
        New York    POINT (-73.993457389558 40.731499671618)       -73.993457  40.731500
        Rio         POINT (-43.2 -22.9)                            -43.200000  -22.900000
        Airport GRU POINT (-46.47313507388693 -23.429382262746415) -46.473135  -23.429382
        ORLY        GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY                          NaN         NaN
```

However, when I try to create a new column to receive the format: (LAT, LONG). The code doesn't work:

```
      df2['Result'] = "(" + df2['LAT'] + "," + df2['LONG'] + ")"
```

The error appears: "UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('float64')) -> None"

I would like the output to be:

```
     NAME            GEO
   Paris            (48.85, 2.31647)
   New York         (40.731499671618, -73.993457389558)
   Rio              (-22.9, -43.2)
   Airport GRU      (-23.429382262746415, -46.47313507388693)
   ORLY             GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.replace`:

```
df['GEO'] = df['GEO'].str.replace('POINT\s+\((.*)\s+(.*)\)', r'(\2, \1)', regex=True)
print(df)

# Output
          NAME                                        GEO
0        Paris                           (48.85, 2.31647)
1     New York        (40.731499671618, -73.993457389558)
2          Rio                             (-22.9, -43.2)
3  Airport GRU  (-23.429382262746415, -46.47313507388693)
4         ORLY                   GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
```

Comment: In this example your code worked perfectly, but when I run it for the complete dataframe, the new 'GEO' column is exactly the same as the previous 'GEO' column (containing POINT(LONG, LAT)). Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: Maybe you have leading and trailing white space. Try: `df['GEO'].str.strip().str.replace(...)`

Comment: Could you share your data (at least the `GEO` column)?

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `str.extract` here:

```
df[["LONG", "LAT"]] = df["GEO"].str.extract(r'POINT \((-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)')
```

For entries which *don't* match the `POINT` format, the above would assign a missing value.  You may replace this with whatever placeholder you want.

Comment: This code only extracts latitude and longitude, right? and to present in the form (LAT, LONG). How should I do?